# Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(System.String, Boolean)

Tags: silverlight

I need to write string to an xml file in Silverlight. When I used the following code, the above mentioned exception "Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(System.String, Boolean)" has occurred.

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\Test.xml", false))
               {
                    sw.Write(root.ToString());
                }

Can anyone help me out in doing writing to xml file in Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight is in a sandboxed mode where it has restricted access.  You can write to "Isolated Storage", but you cannot create files on their hard drive.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile(VS.95).aspx

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/22011/77243.aspx

Comment: I am having exactly same error in XNA project. Even though, I have already added the same file in content reference. What is the way out?